# XPCE for Prolog in compiled files

Tags: swi-prolog, xpce

I have a weird problem with SWI Prolog 6.2.0 and XPCE on Unix.

When I run a prolog program, it works perfectly fine.

```
swipl -f file.pl
```

However, whenever I try and compile the same program

```
swipl -o launch -c file.pl
```

I get an error telling me that pce library is not available

```
source_sink `library(pce)' does not exist
```

I am completely lost as for what could be the reason . . .

Comment: can you post a minimal example? does the program work if you consult and run it or could you be simply missing the pce library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to compile `colour.pl`, a sample from XPCE manual, and I found the same problem you report. Seems that's mandatory to specify the XPCE library path.

I was able to compile with

```
swipl -p library=~/lib/swipl-6.1.13/xpce/prolog/lib/ -o colour -c colour.pl
```

Obtaining the library path is not immediate: the easy way I found: open the source of your file, at line of the first error message (should be something like `:- use_module(library(pce)).`) with the IDE.
Then with the right mouse button open the library source, and from menu `File` click `Save as...`, the box will show the path you can use to compile.

HTH

Comment: interesting, in my version (5.10) it compiles without a problem; so it's probably something that was changed